# Angular loading config with APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular, configuration, angular8

I am trying to load a configuration file (json) via a service using APP_INITIALIZER in Angular 8.
The config contains paths to  images and props for thumbnails

**app-config.json**

```
    {
  "substitutePictureLink": "../images/not_found.png",
  "noImageFound": "../images/404_not_found.png",
  "thumbnailProps": {
  "width": "400",
    "height": "400",
    "format": "PNG",
    "view": "Interior",
    "withdimensions": "true",
    "withdescription": "true"
  }
}
```

For loading the config, I created a Service [app-config-service] which looks like this:

**app-config-service.ts**

```
export class AppConfigService {

public get appConfig(): any {
    return this._appConfig;
}

public set appConfig(value: any) {
    this._appConfig = value;
}

private _appConfig: any;

constructor(
        private _httpClient: HttpClient,
    ) {
        console.log('constructor app-config-service'); 
        this.loadAppConfig();
    }

public loadAppConfig(): any { 
//also tried a promise here
    return this._httpClient.get('../../../assets/configs/app-config.json')
        .pipe(
            take(1)
        )
        .subscribe(
            (config) => {
                this._appConfig = config;
            }
        );

}
```

So I need to load the config on startup;

**app-module.ts**

```
providers: [
    AppConfigService,
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        multi: true,
        deps: [AppConfigService],
        useFactory: (appConfigService: AppConfigService) => {
            return () => {
                return appConfigService.loadAppConfig();
            };
        }
    }
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

When I try to load the configuration, it looks like this:

**some-service.ts**

```
    export class someService {

private _noImageFound = this._appConfigService.appConfig.noImageFound;

constructor(
        private _appConfigService: AppConfigService
    ) {
    }

...

public getThumbnail(): Observable<SafeUrl> {
        return this._httpClient.get(this._apiUrl + '/visual-tree/thumbnail?width=400&height=400', {
            responseType: 'blob',
        })
            .pipe(
                map((res: Blob): SafeUrl => this._blobToUrl.transform(res)),
                catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<string> => {
                    this._logger.error(ErrorMessage.thumbnailNotLoaded, err);
                    return of(this._noImageFound);
                })
            );
    }
...
```

**The error:**

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noImageFound' of undefined

This error occures directly after loging in.
Interesting is also that the constructor of the app-config-service is called two times.
My guess is that the there is something weird going on with the references of that service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because Angular waits only for Promises and not Observables. If you convert the loadAppConfig function to return a Promise (though your comment says so that you have tried) it should fix your issue. I have created the scenario you outlined in this stack, Hope this helps!

change below

```js
return this._httpClient.get('../../../assets/configs/app-config.json') 
              .pipe(take(1)) 
              .subscribe((config) => { this._appConfig = config; });
```

to

```
return this._httpClient.get('assets/config/config.json')
        .toPromise()
        .then(result => {
         this.appConfig = result;
         return Promise.resolve(result);});}
```

Comment: Tank you, it somehow works.
I did not resolve the promise, this may have been the problem.

Comment: according to my knowledge of promises whatever you return from a `then` callback will be wrapped in a promise, unless it's a promise, so you can just `return result` instead of returning a new resolved promise